# How to remove datarows not filtered in grid

Tags: c#, gridview, filter, datatable

I have a DataTable bound to GridView.

After a filter is applied, I want to remove datarows which are not filtered from bound DataTable.

NOTE: I do not want to create new instance of dataTable with filtered rows collection.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: That note seems weird. Creating a new object with the filtered collection is the only logical way to do this. Any explanation why you don't want that?

Comment: The row number in the GridView and the DataTable are the same.  So get a list of selected row from gridvew then delete from DataTable.  You will need to enumerate from last row of datatable to first row : for(int row = dt.Rows.Count - 1; row >= 0; row--)